# Akka HTTP - how to reject requests with unrecognized query parameters

Tags: scala, akka-http

Check the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameter.html) for query parameters on GET requests, e.g.:

```scala
val route =
  parameter("color") { color =>
    complete(s"The color is '$color'")
  }
```

Where color is the accepted parameter.

How can I make the request fail when unaccepted parameters are included? It seems bad to silently accept the unknown parameter. The caller wouldn't be aware that they misspelled the parameter and that it remained at its default value.

Comment: Use case class extraction https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html

Comment: @ccheneson - That's a good suggestion, but it doesn't meet the requirement of rejecting requests that have additional unrecognized query parameters. The only way I can think of for solving that is to extract all of the query parameters from the request context (e.g. using the [parameterMap](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterMap.html) directive) and then validate that all of the query parameter names (the keys in the parameter map) are valid.

Comment: @joost-döbken - In your code example, the `color` parameter is a required parameter. So, if the client includes only unrecognized parameters (no `color` parameter) the request will be rejected. But I think you're asking about how to reject requests when `color` is defined, but there are also other unrecognized parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem would be the following.

1. Extract the full list of query parameters from the request context. This can be done with the [parameterMap](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterMap.html) or [parameterSeq](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterSeq.html) Directive, or by extracting the [requestUri](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/extractUri.html) and then accessing the [query](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.2.9/akka/http/scaladsl/model/Uri.html#query(charset:java.nio.charset.Charset,mode:akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri.ParsingMode):akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri.Query) from the `Uri`.
2. Check that all of the parameter names are valid.
3. Reject the request if there are any unrecognized parameter names.

You could implement a custom `Directive` to encapsulate this behavior and avoid code duplication.